# How to share resources between UWP MediaElement and Win2d CanvasControl?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, directx, uwp, win2d

I'm trying to draw video created in WinRT IBasicVideoEffect to Win2d CanvasControl.

Win2d video effect examples are build on implementing IBasicVideoEffect interface as WinRT component. Bitmaps created from method SetEncodingProperties (IBasicVideoEffect) and from CanvasControl() have different devices and I can't draw one to another.

```
public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
    {
        _mediaElementCanvasRenderTarget = CanvasRenderTarget.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, context.OutputFrame.Direct3DSurface);
    }

public void SetEncodingProperties(VideoEncodingProperties encodingProperties, IDirect3DDevice device)
    {
        canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.CreateFromDirect3D11Device(device);
    }
```

Here I'm getting _mediaElementCanvasRenderTarget, after I draw it on CanvasControl

```
private void canvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(_mediaElementCanvasRenderTarget);
    }
```

Gives error due to different devices. I also tried to set one device to both UIElements but it didn't help.

How to deal this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CanvasBitmap.CopyPixelsFromBitmap to copy your image data from a bitmap of one CanvasDevice to a second bitmap using your other device.  That'll work, but I expect copying between different devices will be fairly expensive.

A far more efficient approach would be to change your design to avoid drawing the video to a CanvasControl at all.  Do all your video processing inside the IBasicVideoEffect implementation, so the output video can be displayed directly using its own XAML video element, while your CanvasControl overlays other non-video content - then each can use its own separate device with no copying required.

Comment: Copying is very expensive. I can't afford that way.

Comment: The reason I can't use processing inside the IBasicVideoEffect is that I must use frame bitmap out of MediaElement bounds. 

I also tried to set MediaElement device to CanvasControl as custom device but it appeared to be expensive too. I found that my both (integrated and discrete) GPUs and CPU are loaded enough. Looks like copying process goes though them all. PCs with one GPU runs faster without CPU overloads.